# How to properly implement a Custom Locked State Image in cxgrid in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl, tcxgrid

I'm using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and would like to implement a custom "locked state image" in a descendant of Tcxgrid (DevExpress VCL 18.2).

I tried to override the `DoPrepareLockedStateImage` protected method as follows:

```
function TZcxGrid.DoPrepareLockedStateImage: Boolean;
begin
   Result: = False;

   if Assigned (OnPrepareLockedStateImage) then
     OnPrepareLockedStateImage (Self, LockedStatePaintHelper.GetImage, Result)
   else
     DoLockedStateImage (Self, LockedStatePaintHelper.GetImage, Result);
end;
```

The above implemented method is causing a Stack Overflow because `LockedStatePaintHelper.GetImage` calls `DoPrepareLockedStateImage` from the grid.

Is this the way to implement this functionality?

Note: I have not found a topic on the Support Center or the DevExpress FAQ. I just found a topic explaining how to use cxgrid's `OnPrepareLockedStateImage` method

Comment: Thanks, But i need Call my Drawer "DoLockedStateImage"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that using `TcxLockedStatePaintHelper`'s `GetImage` during preparation of the state image will cause the Stack Overflow you are experiencing. This is because until the image is completely prepared calling `GetImage` will cause the image to be prepared (again and again in this case).

By directly accessing the protected `Bitmap` property with an accessor this can be circumvented. Using `DoLockedStateImage` (your implementation of drawing another image) your approach would look like this:

```
type
  TcxLockedStatePaintHelperAccess = class(TcxLockedStatePaintHelper);

function TZcxGrid.DoPrepareLockedStateImage: Boolean;
begin
  DoLockedStateImage(Self, TcxLockedStatePaintHelperAccess(LockedStatePaintHelper).Bitmap, Result);
  Result := inherited DoPrepareLockedStateImage;
end;
```